# Enterprise Library CustomTraceListner using Assembly.LoadFrom

Tags: enterprise-library

So I have created a custom trace listener that inherits from the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.CustomTraceListener`.

The trace listener is a utility dll and the utility dll is reading its config file from `utility.dll.config`.

I am using `LogWriterFactory("utility.dll.config")` to create the `LogWriter`. 
When I add a direct reference in a console application to my `utility.dll` then everything works fine.

But if I use `Assembly.LoadFrom("utility.dll")` then I get the following error:

```
The type 'Utility.CustomTraceListner, Utility' cannot be resolved.
```

If I add utility.dll to the GAC then every thing works fine. I can run `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` on the line right above the `logWriterFactory.Create()` and see that `utility.dll` has been loaded.

I can even run `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceFrom("Utility.dll", "Utility.CustomTraceListener")` right before calling `logWriterFactory.Create()` and get an instance without any problems.

We have an internal application that uses `Assembly.LoadFrom` and we would like each assembly that is loaded to have its own config file / log settings that are separate from the loading application.

Any ideas how to fix this without putting the `utility.dll` in the GAC?

I know that the `utility.dll.config` file is correct because it is working fine when the utility assembly is referenced directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiring into the ResolveEventHandler solved the issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx